# How to version control the sql files in github repository

Tags: oracle, git, github

we have a team working on updating the changes in sql files , changes are copied into a folder and uploaded into git.
But its not known to track the sql files. I need some help to versioning the sql files.

Comment: Is your question about how to version actual files (like you would any other text or code files)? Or is your question how to take those files from git and apply the changes to the database?

Comment: we are not able to maintain the version of  update queries in a sql files.

Answer (score 1):

Git can track changes to all the files uploaded weather it is SQL or your other code.

If you want to version control data than you can check dvc

Answer (score 0):

> But its not known to track the sql files.

That's a wrong assumption. I hope you didn't mean `database binary` files, as `.sql` extension files are still **flat text files**. And `git` is pretty good for version control. Any change in the files will be tracked and versioned.